# How to categorize Custom Post Types

Tags: php, wordpress

my issue is a Custom Post Type with a field for categorizing them. I cant find any solution for my Problem so i hope someone here can help me.

The Custom Post Type is called "TEAM" and need a scrolldownmenu with the categories "STAFF" "GUESTS" & "ARTISTS". I've read a lot about custom taxonomies but i dont realy get it.

Comment: Can you post what you tried code?

Comment: why are you doing like this... search good plugin for category and subcategory...or make `TEAM` as category and `parent` for others submenu

Comment: i tried to fix the problem with "Custom Post Types UI" so its more a logic problem. basicly its the normal post type code like the wordpress codex - code. i only need the code - snipped which alows me to build a dropdown to choose a category.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
function register_team_post_type() {
  $labels = array(
    'name' => 'Team',
    'singular_name' => 'Team',
    'add_new' => 'Add New Team',
    'add_new_item' => 'Add New Team',
    'edit_item' => 'Edit Team',
    'new_item' => 'New Team',
    'all_items' => 'All Team Post',
    'view_item' => 'View Team',
    'search_items' => 'Search Team',
    'not_found' =>  'No Team  found',
    'not_found_in_trash' => 'No Team found in Trash', 
    'parent_item_colon' => '',
    'menu_name' => 'Team Post'
  );
  $args = array(
    'labels' => $labels,
    'public' => true,
    'publicly_queryable' => true,
    'show_ui' => true, 
    'show_in_menu' => (is_super_admin()) ? true : false, 
    'query_var' => true,
    'rewrite' => array( 'slug' => 'team' ),
    'capability_type' => 'post',
    'has_archive' => true, 
    'hierarchical' => false,
    'menu_position' => 6,
    //'taxonomies' => array('category'), 
    'supports' => array( 'title', 'editor', 'author', 'custom-fields', 'comments' )


  ); 
   register_post_type( 'team', $args );
}
add_action( 'init', 'register_team_post_type' );

add_action( 'init', 'register_team_category', 0 );

function register_team_category() {
    register_taxonomy( 'categories', 'team', array( 'hierarchical' => true, 'label' => 'Team Categories', 'query_var' => true, 'rewrite' => true ) );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try with this code

```
    $args = array( 'cat' => '1,2,3', 'post_type' => 'team', 'posts_per_page' => -1 );
    $loop = new WP_Query( $args );      
    while ( $loop->have_posts() ) : $loop->the_post();  
         //do what you want;
    endwhile; 
    // end of the loop. ?>
```